# Is it possible to share a set between two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, set

I am currently in the process of designing a database.

I have a table of 20,000+ records, which has a set in it (4 values).   I also am making another table (100+ records) which will have an enum over the same set (1 value from the same set)

Example of current:

```
tbl1                          tbl2
ID   | Letters | Stuff        ID   | Letter | Stuff 
----------------------        ---------------------
0    | A,B,C,D | ...          0    | D      | ...
1    | A,B,C,D |              1    | C      |
2    | C,D     |              2    | A      |
3    | B,C,D   |              3    | D      |
...
```

Is there a way to make sure that the sets are the same, and can I compare the enum and the set?

I also might need to add more options to the set as our data changes.  Would a separate table for that set be necessary, and then an association table for that?

Example of what I just said:

```
tbl1                tbl2             
ID | Stuff          ID   | LetterID | Stuff 
------------        ------------------------  
0  | ...            0    | 3        | ...
1  |                1    | 2        |
2  |                2    | 0        |
3  |                3    | 3        |
...

tblLetters          tblLetters1 (Association table)
ID | Letter         tbl1Id | letterId
------------        ------------------
0  | A              0      | 0
1  | B              0      | 1
2  | C              0      | 2
3  | D              0      | 3
...?                ...
```

My only major concern with this is whether the size of the association table would be too big (most of the rows in tbl1 will have all 4 elements of the set).

Thank you!  Sorry if I didn't explain my problem very well.  I'm very green when it comes to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution seems fine, comma separated values in 1 column should normally be avoided. You might not need an ID, and I'd drop the ENUM type for the column, and use the actual type / column definition of the letter in tblLetters:

```
tbl1                tbl2             
ID | Stuff          ID   | Letter   | Stuff 
------------        ------------------------  
0  | ...            0    | D        | ...
1  |                1    | C        |
2  |                2    | A        |
3  |                3    | D        |

tblLetters          tblLetters1 (Association table)
Letter              tbl1Id | letter
------------        ------------------
A                   0      | A
B                   0      | B
C                   0      | C
D                   0      | D
```

Possibly add a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to tblLetters1.letter & tbl2.letter to enforce an existing letter from tblLetters.

And 80K rows in total is not many by any standard, it should be fine (use the proper indexes though)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at your question....
So from what I understand, you just want to make sure the tables have the "options" or "variables" in the enum and set fields.

What you can do is:

```
Show create table tbl1;
```

What you should see is

```
Create table tbl1   
(id int unsigned,  
stuff set('A','B','C','D'),
.....)  

Show create table tbl2;  
Create table tbl2   
(id int unsigned,  
stuff enum('A','B','C','D'),
.....)
```

All you would need to to, technically, is make sure both tables have the same variables.   You can do this with a script or just be aware of it when you do an ALTER TABLE.